# Angularjs: prevent binding

Tags: angularjs, binding

How can i prevent binding in this case:

```
$scope.data = [{i:0, a:0}, {i:0, a:0}, {i:0, a:0}];
$scope.twoofthedata = [$scope.data, $scope.data];
```

so that $scope.twoofthedata[0] is indipendent from $scope.twoofthedata[1]

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bdVetGyKbDODmyTx3vMc?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, objects are manipulated [by reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). This is not an Angular binding issue.

However Angular enables you to bypass this language constraint via the [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) method, which creates a deep copy of a given object.

```
$scope.data = [{i:0, a:0}, {i:0, a:0}, {i:0, a:0}];

// Manually call `angular.copy` on each member
$scope.twoofthedata = [
  angular.copy($scope.data),
  angular.copy($scope.data)
];

// Cleaner version (using `Array.prototype.map`)
$scope.twoofthedata = [$scope.data, $scope.data].map(angular.copy);
```

However you should be warned that a deep copy could be very expensive, and therefore only be used when truly necessary.

FYI: if you encounter a similar issue but not using Angular, you could use Lodash which also has a [deep clone method](http://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep).

Comment: had some problems with $watch(), and changed    `angular.copy($scope.data) > $.extend(true, {}, $scope.data);` now is not showing RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: What kind of problem did you have with `$watch`?

Comment: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: And you have the same problem using `$.extend`?